# What was the power source in I, Robot?

Tags: i-robot-2004

Famously in the film when Spooner is riding on his motorbike with Dr Calvin, she asks him something like 'this doesn't run on gas does it?  You do know gas explodes!'.  Her obvious horror suggests that in 2035 humanity relies upon an alternate power supply than gas (or even fossil fuels).  Is there any indication of what this is (I don't recall seeing any nuclear power plants or solar panels), or are we meant to simply guess what it would be?

Comment: I hope not a nuclear source. Seems kind of silly to complain about gas exploding when you're sitting on nuclear material...

Comment: I don't think you were supposed to think about it at all. I think it was simply to compare future tech to something concrete that the viewers would know, and to provide some humor.

Comment: @calccrypto nevertheless in a society where basically electricity runs everything, it's still a fairly important question I think

Comment: Well, the plot of the movie was about robot/human interaction, singularity, technophobia, and [Converse All Stars](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HpIZrOH4zc). What do power supplies have to do with any of those things? How would mentioning the power supply contribute to the story, beyond the mentioned scene?

Comment: Between batteries and non-exploding power sources we have today (solar, hydroelectric, wind, maybe others I'm forgetting...) her incredulity may be a regular occurrence within our lifetimes...

Comment: @Izkata are you saying batteries don't explode? the wording is slightly awkward. Also http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2093/would-a-large-quantity-of-gasoline-in-a-closed-container-explode-violently-when

Comment: @calccrypto Exploding batteries are due to catastrophic failure, gas engines run off of continuous controlled "explosions".  A similar statement is sometimes made in sci-fi series where energy weapons are standard and a character is incredulous at modern reallife conventional weapons:  "It's like trying to control an explosion!"

Comment: @Izkata got ya. and controlled explosions were not what Dr. Calvin was talking about. Even if she did know about controlled explosions, the line was written for the average audience, who expect gas tanks to explode

Comment: @calccrypto Yeah, I don't see how you could make the phrase technically correct and still natural-sounding, so I'm guessing they figured that was a good enough intermediate phrase, but that they may still have had "controlled explosions" in mind

Comment: @calccrypto the all-stars was an antique just like his CD player. Spooner liked antiques.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the original Asimov source material is an acceptable basis for an answer, Earth received power from [space-based solar power stations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-based_solar_power) as described in the short story "Reason."  The main characters in the story were Gregory Powell and Mike Donovan, who were young contemporaries of the Susan Calvin character featured in the movie.  Each solar collector near the sun gathered incoming energy and converted it into a concentrated photon stream, probably microwaves.  The photon streams were aimed at a receiving station on Earth and other destinations in the solar system as demand warranted.